# Font-Face is not smooth in WebKit

Tags: css, webkit, font-face

Fontface is working great in firefox and explorer but chrome. How can I fix it ?

http://goo.gl/Bgt4J

Comment: 1) Please expand that URL 2) Gecko is Firefox's engine, which one is not working for you?

Comment: Thank you. I don't want google to index my link so I wanted to put it that way.

Comment: Google isn't going to index your link if you put a noindex header in your page.

Comment: if I put my page's link here google will come and index this page at some point, and when it does if my customer searches his website on google stackoverflow will show up and they will be able to see that I dont know what I'm doing. Thank you

Comment: http://eligrey.com/blog/post/better-font-smoothing-in-google-chrome-on-windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://eligrey.com/blog/post/better-font-smoothing-in-google-chrome-on-windows

Answer (score 1):

That's an official bug in Google Chrome, not solved even in March 2013. But there's a workaround, see my long answer here in a similar post: [Is there any "font smoothing" in Google Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487427/font-smoothing)

The workaround is `-webkit-text-stroke: 1px`